# Why do these Android controls look peculiar on Galaxy S?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, rendering

I'm experiencing issues with both this dialog and another Activity - where it's an EditText control that looks wrong - and in both cases it seems that the center of the control is shifted up by one pixel, or the sides down by one. I'm guessing that the regions in question are defined by a 9-patch.

Has anyone else experienced this, and knows how it might be resolved? Could it be something to do with sub-pixel rendering - as with the iPhone, where non-integer positioning of UI controls causes blurriness? I've also noticed issues with table dividers disappearing at certain offsets (surely a subpixel issue) - but on both this phone and an HTC device.

[image: Button at the bottom of the screen is deformed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the rendering issues went away when I adjusted the minimum SDK level up to 5 from 3.